# What is happening here using $u \bmod 1$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The context of this question is [coarsening fronts in Allen-Cahn](http://www.math.umn.edu/~scheel/preprints/coarsening.pdf)
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+u(1-u^2),
$$
in particular Figure 1.2 for $k\sim 0$ (on p. 4) where we can see plateaus at $\pm 1$.

In the picture below which I attached here this seems to be the second picture from above. ($u\text{ mod }1$).

My question is: What does this $u\text{ mod 1}$ mean and why do we get the picture on the top when not considering $u\text{ mod 1}$ but $u$ (some kind of 'staircase')?

Moreover, what is meant by "modulated traveling wave"?
[image]

Comment: I think we won't be able to figure out what you are asking without more context. Where does this picture come from? Course notes? If so, what course and what part of the material is it trying to explain?

Comment: I added details.

Comment: I think it is a not so standard way of talking about the fractional part of a number.